# PIGPIO without sudo

Tags: pigpio, permissions, sudo

I am working on setting up an automated deployment of an executable using the PIGPIO C bindings to a Pi Zero. I copy the executable to the pi (into a directory on `pi` user's desktop) as expected, but when I try to run it, I get a permissions error:

```
initCheckPermitted:
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|Sorry, you don't have permission to run this program.    |
|Try running as root, e.g. precede the command with sudo. |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

It seems this problem can be solved by setting the executable to be owned by `root` and using a permission setting like `4775`. This seems to allow me to run the executable while logged in as `pi`.

Unfortunately though, when I then copy a new version of the executable in, the ownership permissions stay the same, but the sticky bit is removed and I can no longer run the executable. It seems like the right answer would be "figure out how to run the executable when it's owned by `pi`". Is this possible? Can I change something so PIGPIO can access the needed hardware without having to do weird things with the permissions?

[This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66890/accessing-pwm-module-without-root-permissions) seems to be a similar issue, but with PWM specifically. I see a `gpio` group but `pi` is already in that group. Is this question related or completely misleading me?

Comment: If you can copy a new file to the Pi, you can also set the permissions on it.

Comment: Have a look at using the C I/F to the pigpio daemon.  That will be quite suitable for a lot of usage. http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html

Comment: @joan how does that differ from the standard pigpio library? Will it not run into the permissions issues seen with the other?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev In theory, yes, but that is proving difficult with the automated deployment I am using. I can change permissions, but my question is whether there is another way to fix the issue without using special permission bits.

Comment: The pigpio daemon will need to be started with sudo. Programs linked against pigpiod_if2 do not.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will look into that!

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you have the source code of your C program. If so, add these lines:

At the top:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Near the start of main():

```
if (setuid(getuid()) < 0)
{
        printf("Privilege change failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

You can use any other error notification, instead of the printf.

See `man -s 2 setuid` for details.

Comment: This isn't a C program originally, it is an executable from Kotlin Native that is linked to the PIGPIO library. I am favoring a solution that lets the library be run from the `pi` user without needing special permission bits and `sudo`, if one exists, in part because I want to avoid fiddling with parts of the C library.

Comment: -1. This will fail unless the process is already privileged (e.g. running as `root`), at which point there is no purpose in `setuid`.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I copied these lines (I'm afraid I can't find the reference) for my first ever Pi program; believing it was necessary to access GPIO. It most certainly does not fail, in the sense that I have never experienced the error message. I can't check now, but IIRC, the executable is owned by pi and has default permissions (755).

Comment: Think about it: if any executable with default permissions can simply call `setuid(getuid())` to run as `root`, what is the purpose of having `sudo` and the sticky bit?